# How to bevel a plane made of bezier?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel, extrude

For a while I've been trying to bevel a plane made with Bezier Curve. My goal is to bevel the entire rim outwards.

1. How can I extrude so that the thickness of the surface is always the same in all directions (or in the direction of the normal)?
2. If the thickness is the same everywhere, I thought I'd make a loop cut and scale outwards to then start the bevel here.

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: When you extrude on Z it's normal that the length along the normal is smaller, if you want the same length you need to use the Extrude Faces Along Normals, but it won't be an extrusion on Z anymore.

Comment: Great moonbots! Thanks, ALT-E solved the first problem. But now how can I scale along normals? I can't find any informations about that.

Comment: Ok, just found it. ALT+S solved the second problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

|  | New tool Unlocked! |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | [Shrink Fatten](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/shrink-fatten.html#bpy-ops-transform-shrink-fatten) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> |  |

This tool moved selected vertices/edges/faces along their own normal (perpendicular to the face):

[image]

After extruding upwards, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or RMB to cancel moving, and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to move points along normals instead

After adding rim, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale this rim evenly  along normals

Comment: Thanks Crantisz! Just found it based on moonboots.

Answer (score 1):

So easy when you know how. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]